# Scroll down hint at bottom of browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-experience

I'm working on a huge single page website and would like to show an scroll down hint (icon or something like that) at the bottom of the window when the user visits the website.

The hint should vanish when the visitor either scrolls down or clicks on the icon. I've seen this on several websites which I can't remember now unfortunately. Already been searching on but with no results as I'm probably searching with the wrong keywords...

Anyone has any directions on where to start to achieve this?

Comment: If you're working on a "huge SPA", this should be pretty trivial to do yourself. At least attempt it and show what you've written with an explanation of what's not working

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I was just looking for advice. Smooth scroll was already implemented on the anchor links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a start to get the scroll hint working. Now on styling, that's up to you but I would personally do something like `position: absolute` and then work from there and give it a `zIndex` about everything on the page.

```
$(window).scroll( function() {
    if($(document).scrollTop() == 0 ) {
        // SHOW scroll hint
    } else {
        // HIDE scroll hint
    }
});
```

I did this on one of my own web pages.

http://codepen.io/pattmorter/pen/mFDLs

Just check out the javascript and the css.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to achieve. Thanks for the Codepen link. I'll give it a try and modify it a bit to my needs.

Comment: And if you want it to fade in and out just look up jQuery animations or an even better option would be to assign new styles on scroll and use css3 transition animations.

Comment: Yeah, that's on my mind too.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would need an ID on your icon/link and then have two event listeners. One for clicking on the ID itself and the other onscroll. Once either of those events are fired you can call `.remove()`

Comment: Thans for your suggestion. I think I'lll remove the link to the ID as that's already implemented in the regular menu at the top.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know where to start, try to read reference of [window](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp) object. For visibility change you can use `opacity`, and `position` attribute to make it fixed at bottom of screen.